# Testing an Angular Form with Jest - fill and query form fields

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest

How can I query and fill form fields in a Jest test script? My working environment is Angular 13.

In saw similar posts and was inspired in using alternative answers. But I keep on getting errors that properties don't exist.

My simplified form is:

```
<form name="frmProduct">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2" for="ProductPrice">Product price</label>
    <input class="col-8 form-control" id="ProductPrice" name="ProductPrice" [(ngModel)]="productPrice" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <input class="col-2 btn btn-warning pl-1" (click)="clear()" type="button" value="Clear">
    <input class="col-2 btn btn-success pl-2" (click)="save()" type="button" value="Save">
  </div>
</form>
```

Try-1: My Jest test code is ... having errors that the property does not exist.

```
describe('ProductFormComponent', () => {
  let component: ProductcomponentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductcomponentComponent>;
  let button: HTMLElement;

  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  });
  beforeEach( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProductcomponentComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ]
    }).compileComponents(); 
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductcomponentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // Below is the synchronous way. I also tried the async way via fakeAsync( .. )
  it('should calculate tax based on base price when save button is clicked', () => {
    productPrice = 4000;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect( getFormElementValue( fixture.nativeElement, '#ProductPrice')).toEqual( '4000')
  });
  
  function getFormElementValue( componentForm: any, selector:string): string {
    return componentForm.querySelector( selector).value;
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: with the help of '@rfprod' solved it. Thank you very much!

**Set via component and read via form field:**

```
it('should calculate tax based on base price when save button is clicked', async () => {
  component.productPrice = 4000;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then( () => {
    expect(getFormElementValue(fixture.nativeElement, '#ProductPrice')).toEqual('4000')
  });
});

function getFormElementValue( componentForm: any, selector:string): string {
  return componentForm.querySelector( selector).value;
}
```

**Setting and reading form fields:**

```
it('should calculate tax based on base price when save button is clicked', async () => {
  component.product.BasePrice = 4000;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then( () => {
    setFormElementValue(fixture.nativeElement, '#BasePrice', 5000)
  });
  fixture.whenStable().then( () => {
    expect(getFormElementValue(fixture.nativeElement, '#BasePrice')).toEqual('5000')
  });
});

function setFormElementValue(componentForm: any, selector: string, value: number) {
  let element = componentForm.querySelector( selector);
  element.value = value;
  element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: What is your in _component_ code? Also, can you update the final version of your jest test?

Finally, can you specify _what exactly are you trying to achieve_?

Comment: Thank you for helping!!
Problem solved. See the updated question after the EDIT tag.

Comment: No problem. be sure to mark his answer as valid, if that's what solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things wrong in your test. One, your jest test seems incomplete. Like, you need to set the product price on the *component* property.

Two, when you're getting the price, you need to target the selector a bit better.

Here are a few examples that worked for me:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormComponent } from './form.component';
import { EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

describe('FormComponent', () => {
  let component: FormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FormComponent ],
      imports: [FormsModule],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set the price in the form, when we set it in the model', () => {
    component.productPrice = '4000';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#ProductPrice').value).toEqual('');
    fixture.whenStable()
      .then(() => {
        expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#ProductPrice').value).toEqual('4000');
      });
  });

  it('should do this with "waitForAsync"', waitForAsync(() => {
    component.productPrice = '4000';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#ProductPrice').value).toEqual('');
    fixture.whenStable()
      .then(() => {
        expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#ProductPrice').value).toEqual('4000');
      });
  }));

  // maybe you wanna create an output and listen for changes?
  // like, save will output productPrice + 20%
  // your component has:
  //     @Output() priceWithTax = new EventEmitter<string>();
  // and the save method:
  //    this.priceWithTax.emit( <product price increased by 20 %> )
  it('should do this with "waitForAsync"', waitForAsync((done: any) => {
    component.priceWithTax
      .subscribe((value: number) => {
        expect(value).toEqual(4800);
        done();
      })
    component.productPrice = '4000';
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));
});
```

My component template looks like yours:

```
<form name="frmProduct">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2" for="ProductPrice">Product price</label>
    <input class="col-8 form-control" id="ProductPrice" name="ProductPrice" [(ngModel)]="productPrice" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <input class="col-2 btn btn-warning pl-1" (click)="clear()" type="button" value="Clear">
    <input class="col-2 btn btn-success pl-2" (click)="save()" type="button" value="Save">
  </div>
</form>
```

And my component class is like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-jest-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() priceWithTax = new EventEmitter<number>();
  productPrice = '';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('initialized')
  }

  clear() {
    this.productPrice = '';
  }

  save() {
    console.log('PP:', this.productPrice);
    const price = parseInt(this.productPrice, 10);
    const value = Math.round(price * 1.2)
    this.priceWithTax.emit(value)
  }

}
```

These are the results I get:

[image]

---

**Edit: here's an updated, sync version**

So, just for the sake of completeness, here's an updated version for you, with ReactiveFormsModule. Reactive Forms *are synchronous* and while they add a bit of boilerplate in one place, you save it in many others.

So my template would have

```
<input [formControl]="productPriceControl">
```

instead of

```
<input [(ngModel)]="productPrice">
```

My component would have:

```
class FormComponent {
  productPriceControl = new FormControl('');
  ...
  // here's how to read the value from the control
  save() {
    const currentPrice = this.productPriceControl.value;
    // calculate price with tax
  }
  // here's how to write the value
  clear() {
    this.productPriceControl.setValue('');
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, my test looks like this:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormComponent } from './form.component';
import { EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

describe('FormComponent', () => {
  let component: FormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FormComponent ],
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set the price in the form, when we set it in the model', () => {
    component.productPriceControl.setValue('4000');
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#ProductPrice').value).toEqual('4000');
  });
  it('should set the price in the control, when we set it in the template', () => {
    const input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#ProductPrice');
    input.value = '4000';
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    expect(component.productPriceControl.value).toEqual('4000')
  });
});
```

As you can see, there is no *asynchronous* code, no `waitForAsync` or anything. Everything is synced right away.

Hope that helps for some future work.

Comment: Very nice solution as well!!!! Lots to learn from. I did +1. Will either answer mark as the answer. BOTH are gooed, yours even better. THANK YOU.

Comment: Yep, rfprod's answer was more direct and aimed directly at solving your problem (with just the missing `whenStable`, needed because template forms are async), and mine was more aimed at helping you understand the whole a bit more.

Comment: I needed this statement at the start of the test suite to get it running. beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  });

Answer (score 2):

seems like it should be

```
it('should calculate tax based on base price when save button is clicked', () => {
    component.productPrice = 4000;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect( getFormElementValue( fixture.nativeElement, '#ProductPrice')).toEqual( '4000')
  });
```

I'd suggest using the reactive forms instead of `[(ngModel)]` https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: I had to make it async. Then it works. THANK YOU very much!